# Need Shell Script to download file from ftp link?

Tags: ftp, download, wget, file-transfer

I need to get this file
ftp://1034733:ze3Kt699vy14@idx.living.net/idx_fl_ftp_down/idx_ftmyersbeach_dn/ftmyersbeach_data.zip
to my site's server.  THis seems like an easy enough task... but, I cannot find a solution at this point.  PHP doesn't seem to be capable of getting the job done.  Wget was my next thought, however, godaddy's installation of wget gives me a 'connection refused' problem (although it wget works for this on my computer - mac os x 10.6).  I'm now thinking it has to do with godaddy's side of things, but I am stuck with what I have.  My goal here is to write a script that will execute through a cron job (i need to download this file every day).  Someone please help!  I am to the point of ripping my hair out of my head!  I've spent the last two weeks on this!
Also, I've tried using curl through the shell and wget.  both have failed.  Unfortunately I only have access to this link, I do not have an ftp login for idx.living.net

Comment: Username and password are provided in this link - user: 1034733 - password: ze3Kt699vy14 - When I use the link with wget, it works for me `wget ftp://1034733:ze3Kt699vy14@idx.living.net/idx_fl_ftp_down/idx_ftmyersbeach_dn/ftmyersbeach_data.zip`

Comment: Yes wget works fine on my personal computer as well, but I'm hosting the site on godaddy, and I'm getting a connection refused issue there

Comment: I think you are not allow to establish outgoing connections on your server. Please contact the administrators if it is possible to open the specific port on the firewall for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

# ftpget - given an ftp: style URL, unwrap it, and try to obtain the file using ftp.

if [ $# -ne 2 ] && [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 ftp://... username [password]" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Typical URL: ftp://ftp.ncftp.com/2.7.1/ncftpd-2.7.1.tar.gz

if [ "$(echo $1 | cut -c1-6)" != "ftp://" ] ; then
  echo "$0: Malformed url. I need it to start with ftp://" >&2;
  exit 1
fi

server="$(echo $1 | cut -d/ -f3)"
filename="/$(echo $1 | cut -d/ -f4-)"
basefile="$(basename $filename)"
username="$(echo $2)"
password=""
if [ $# -eq 3 ] ; then
  password="$(echo $3)"
fi

#rm $basefile
echo ${0}: Downloading $basefile from server $server

ftp -n << EOF
open $server
user $username $password
bin
get $filename $basefile
quit
EOF

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
  #chmod +x $basefile
  ls -l $basefile
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful for the members, that are not so familiar with shell scripting ;-)

Comment: I'm sure this is an extremely basic question, but i'm not extremely familiar with shell scripting, so: How do i put my url into this script?

Comment: okay, quick addition.  I tried using the ftp commands, everything works fine... except, it tells me the file or folder doesn't exist, then closes the connection!  Any ideas?
ftp -n << EOF
open idx.living.net
user 1034733 ze3Kt699vy14
bin
get "/idx_fl_ftp_down/idx_ftmyersbeach_dn/ft‌​myersbeach_data.zip" "ftmyersbeach_data.zip"
quit
EOF

here's the error

550 /idx_fl_ftp_down/idx_ftmyersbeach_dn/ft‌​myersbeach_data.zip: No such file or folder.
221 Service closing control connection.

Comment: One more comment, sorry.  I fixed the last error, it was a typo.  But I now have a new issue with godaddy!  The ftp script works on my local machine.. but it doesn't work on my godaddy server... I keep getting a connection refused error. Why would this happen?

Comment: Okay, I have a solution now.  Just incase anyone is having the same problem, I set up a cron job to run my own version of the above script that will download the file, unzip it and upload the necessary file to my site!  Thank you guys for all your help!  It is much appreciated!